# How to disable solr reindexing while save model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-solr

I'd like to disable solr reindexing, while save my model. Example:

```
def show
  @item = Item.where(params[:id]).first
  @item.views_count += 1
  @item.save
  render :show_item
end
```

Field `views_count` is not searchable. But solr take 2 seconds while saving my model. Can I switch off solr reindexing at this case?

Answer (score 0):

**variant 1**

@item.update_column(:views_count, count)

**variant 2**

```
class MySearchableModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable :auto_index => false do
    bla bla
  end
end

class AdministratorController < ApplicationController
  def make_public
    bla bla
    MySearchableModel.reindex
    Sunspot.commit
    bla bla
  end
end
```

**variant 3, like 2**

```
..
Sunspot.index @item
Sunspot.commit
..
```